# How to calculate the times change from A to B, B to C in a vector by R

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector, for example, (A,A,B,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A), so are there any functions I can use to get the times change from A to B, A to A, B to A and B to B without a loop.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the meaning of change from A to A ? In your example, how many times it changes from A to A ?

Comment: The best way to pose this kind of question is to give a small example that illustrates the problem, and exactly what you expect to be output from that example.

Comment: In my vector, there should be 1 time from A change to A, 1 time change from B to B, and 4 times from A to B, and 4 times from B to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this (quick'n'dirty) way:

```
vals <- c('A','A','B','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A')

transitions <- paste(vals[-length(vals)],vals[-1],sep='->')

ret <-  do.call(rbind,
                by(transitions,transitions, FUN=function(tr){list(length(tr))}))

> ret
     [,1]
A->A    1
A->B    4
B->A    4
B->B    1
```

Or, as correctly pointed out by @asb, you can use `table` function instead of `do.call(...`:

```
ret <- table(transitions)

> ret
transitions
A->A A->B B->A B->B 
   1    4    4    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rle` base function:

```
vals <- c('A','A','B','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A')
tt= rle(vals)
str(tt)
> print(tt)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:9] 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  values : chr [1:9] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A"
# number of changes 
length(tt$values)-1
# number of changes A->B
length(which(diff(as.numeric(as.factor(tt$values)))>0))
# number of changes B->A
length(which(diff(as.numeric(as.factor(tt$values)))<0))
```

Comment: `rle`, rather like beer (per H. Simpson), is the source of, and the answer to, all of life's `R` problems :-0

Answer (score 1):

Just changing a small part from digEmAll's answer:

```
aa = LETTERS[sample.int(2, 20, TRUE)]
table(paste0(aa[-1], aa[-length(aa)]))
```